# YouTube Analytics API: How to enter key | Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, analytics, youtube-analytics

I am using this sample code for my YouTube analytics API:

```
(function() {
// Retrieve your client ID from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} at
// {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}.
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
];
var ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
// Keep track of the currently authenticated user's YouTube channel ID.
var channelId;
// For information about the Google Chart Tools API, see:
// https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart']});
// Upon loading, the Google APIs JS client automatically invokes this callback.
// See http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication
window.onJSClientLoad = function() {
gapi.auth.init(function() {
window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
});
};
// Attempt the immediate OAuth 2.0 client flow as soon as the page loads.
// If the currently logged-in Google Account has previously authorized
// the client specified as the OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID, then the authorization
// succeeds with no user intervention. Otherwise, it fails and the
// user interface that prompts for authorization needs to display.
function checkAuth() {
gapi.auth.authorize({
client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
immediate: true
}, handleAuthResult);
}
// Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
if (authResult) {
// Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
// content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
$('.pre-auth').hide();
$('.post-auth').show();
loadAPIClientInterfaces();
} else {
// Authorization was unsuccessful. Show content related to prompting for
// authorization and hide content that should be visible if authorization
// succeeds.
$('.post-auth').hide();
$('.pre-auth').show();
// Make the #login-link clickable. Attempt a non-immediate OAuth 2.0
// client flow. The current function is called when that flow completes.
$('#login-link').click(function() {
gapi.auth.authorize({
client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
immediate: false
}, handleAuthResult);
});
}
}
// Load the client interfaces for the YouTube Analytics and Data APIs, which
// are required to use the Google APIs JS client. More info is available at
// http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted#Loading_the_Client
function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
gapi.client.load('youtubeAnalytics', 'v1', function() {
// After both client interfaces load, use the Data API to request
// information about the authenticated user's channel.
getUserChannel();
});
});
}
// Call the Data API to retrieve information about the currently
// authenticated user's YouTube channel.
function getUserChannel() {
// Also see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
// Setting the "mine" request parameter's value to "true" indicates that
// you want to retrieve the currently authenticated user's channel.
mine: true,
part: 'id,contentDetails'
});
request.execute(function(response) {
if ('error' in response) {
displayMessage(response.error.message);
} else {
// We need the channel's channel ID to make calls to the Analytics API.
// The channel ID value has the form "UCdLFeWKpkLhkguiMZUp8lWA".
channelId = response.items[0].id;
// Retrieve the playlist ID that uniquely identifies the playlist of
// videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel. This value has
// the form "UUdLFeWKpkLhkguiMZUp8lWA".
var uploadsListId = response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
// Use the playlist ID to retrieve the list of uploaded videos.
getPlaylistItems(uploadsListId);
}
});
}
// Call the Data API to retrieve the items in a particular playlist. In this
// example, we are retrieving a playlist of the currently authenticated user's
// uploaded videos. By default, the list returns the most recent videos first.
function getPlaylistItems(listId) {
// See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistitems/list
var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
playlistId: listId,
part: 'snippet'
});
request.execute(function(response) {
if ('error' in response) {
displayMessage(response.error.message);
} else {
if ('items' in response) {
// The jQuery.map() function iterates through all of the items in
// the response and creates a new array that only contains the
// specific property we're looking for: videoId.
var videoIds = $.map(response.items, function(item) {
return item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
});
// Now that we know the IDs of all the videos in the uploads list,
// we can retrieve information about each video.
getVideoMetadata(videoIds);
} else {
displayMessage('There are no videos in your channel.');
}
}
});
}
// Given an array of video IDs, this function obtains metadata about each
// video and then uses that metadata to display a list of videos.
function getVideoMetadata(videoIds) {
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
// The 'id' property's value is a comma-separated string of video IDs.
id: videoIds.join(','),
part: 'id,snippet,statistics'
});
request.execute(function(response) {
if ('error' in response) {
displayMessage(response.error.message);
} else {
// Get the jQuery wrapper for the #video-list element before starting
// the loop.
var videoList = $('#video-list');
$.each(response.items, function() {
// Exclude videos that do not have any views, since those videos
// will not have any interesting viewcount Analytics data.
if (this.statistics.viewCount == 0) {
return;
}
var title = this.snippet.title;
var videoId = this.id;
// Create a new &lt;li&gt; element that contains an &lt;a&gt; element.
// Set the &lt;a&gt; element's text content to the video's title, and
// add a click handler that will display Analytics data when invoked.
var liElement = $('<li>');
var aElement = $('<a>');
// Setting the href value to '#' ensures that the browser renders the
// &lt;a&gt; element as a clickable link.
aElement.attr('href', '#');
aElement.text(title);
aElement.click(function() {
displayVideoAnalytics(videoId);
});
// Call the jQuery.append() method to add the new &lt;a&gt; element to
// the &lt;li&gt; element, and the &lt;li&gt; element to the parent
// list, which is identified by the 'videoList' variable.
liElement.append(aElement);
videoList.append(liElement);
});
if (videoList.children().length == 0) {
// Display a message if the channel does not have any viewed videos.
displayMessage('Your channel does not have any videos that have been viewed.');
}
}
});
}
// This function requests YouTube Analytics data for a video and displays
// the results in a chart.
function displayVideoAnalytics(videoId) {
if (channelId) {
// To use a different date range, modify the ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS
// variable to a different millisecond delta as desired.
var today = new Date();
var lastMonth = new Date(today.getTime() - ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS);
var request = gapi.client.youtubeAnalytics.reports.query({
// The start-date and end-date parameters must be YYYY-MM-DD strings.
'start-date': formatDateString(lastMonth),
'end-date': formatDateString(today),
// At this time, you need to explicitly specify channel==channelId.
// See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/#ids
ids: 'channel==' + channelId,
dimensions: 'day',
sort: 'day',
// See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports
// for details about the different filters and metrics you can request
// if the "dimensions" parameter value is "day".
metrics: 'views',
filters: 'video==' + videoId
});
request.execute(function(response) {
// This function is called regardless of whether the request succeeds.
// The response contains YouTube Analytics data or an error message.
if ('error' in response) {
displayMessage(response.error.message);
} else {
displayChart(videoId, response);
}
});
} else {
// The currently authenticated user's channel ID is not available.
displayMessage('The YouTube channel ID for the current user is not available.');
}
}
// This boilerplate code takes a Date object and returns a YYYY-MM-DD string.
function formatDateString(date) {
var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = padToTwoCharacters(date.getMonth() + 1);
var dd = padToTwoCharacters(date.getDate());
return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
}
// If number is a single digit, prepend a '0'. Otherwise, return the number
// as a string.
function padToTwoCharacters(number) {
if (number < 10) {
return '0' + number;
} else {
return number.toString();
}
}
// Call the Google Chart Tools API to generate a chart of Analytics data.
function displayChart(videoId, response) {
if ('rows' in response) {
hideMessage();
// The columnHeaders property contains an array of objects representing
// each column's title -- e.g.: [{name:"day"},{name:"views"}]
// We need these column titles as a simple array, so we call jQuery.map()
// to get each element's "name" property and create a new array that only
// contains those values.
var columns = $.map(response.columnHeaders, function(item) {
return item.name;
});
// The google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() function wants an array
// of arrays. The first element is an array of column titles, calculated
// above as "columns". The remaining elements are arrays that each
// represent a row of data. Fortunately, response.rows is already in
// this format, so it can just be concatenated.
// See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable
var chartDataArray = [columns].concat(response.rows);
var chartDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartDataArray);
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(chartDataTable, {
// Additional options can be set if desired as described at:
// https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw
title: 'Views per Day of Video ' + videoId
});
} else {
displayMessage('No data available for video ' + videoId);
}
}
// This helper method displays a message on the page.
function displayMessage(message) {
$('#message').text(message).show();
}
// This helper method hides a previously displayed message on the page.
function hideMessage() {
$('#message').hide();
}
})();
```

When I insert in the client ID, it says this:

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires
>   signup.

I researched this, and it means I have to also put in the API Key. Where do I do this?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before

> gapi.auth.authorize

put

> gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);

Comment: you can also use setOauthToken()